# Vue Storybook Jest Addon configuration problem

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, storybook

I wonder if someone using the jest addon can share it's Vue Storybook configuration, since I can't seem to make it work. I've tried the global mode:

In Storybook's config.js:

```
import { withTests } from '@storybook/addon-jest';

import results from '../.jest-test-results.json';

addDecorator(
  withTests({
    results,
  })
);
```

And inside my Story:

```
storiesOf('Elements/Tag', module)
  .addParameters({ jest: ['ThuleTag'] })
  .addDecorator(VueInfoAddon)
  .addDecorator(withTests({ results })('ThuleTag'))
  .add('Squared',
    withNotes(_notes)(() => ({
      components: {ThuleTag},
      template: _template,
      propsDescription: {
        size: 'medium / small / mini',
        type: 'success / info/warning / danger'
      }
    })),
  )
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object(...)(...).addParameters is not a function
```

I've also tried the local way:
In my Story:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/vue'
import { withNotes } from '@storybook/addon-notes'
import results from '../../../jest-test-results.json'
import { withTests } from '@storybook/addon-jest'
import ThuleTag from '../../components/ui/elements/ThuleTag.vue'

let _notes = `A simple wrapper for the Elements el-tag, that accepts the same <i>type</i> and <i>size</i> props`

let _template = `<thule-tag
  size="small"
  key="name">Tag Namez
</thule-tag>`

storiesOf('Elements/Tag', module)
  .addDecorator(withTests({ results }))
  .add('Squared',
    withNotes(_notes)(() => ({
      components: {ThuleTag},
      template: _template,
      propsDescription: {
        size: 'medium / small / mini',
        type: 'success / info/warning / danger'
      }
    })),
    {
      jest: ['ThuleTag.test.js'],
    }
  )
```

Here I get this error:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined"
```

And the Tests tab is shown with this message:

```
This story has tests configured, but no file was found
```

Can someone point me what's messing things up please?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like storybook jest addon is not supported for Vue.js for now
https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/blob/master/ADDONS_SUPPORT.md

Answer (score 0):

Ok, about first error

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined"
```

I think that you should check your babel-config, It seems like you forget some presets for your framework.

About second question

```
This story has tests configured, but no file was found
```

That problem happens from Jest and storybook/addon-jest want to get with equals api, but  they can't. In last versions of Jest, output file structure has `options.testResults` , but storybook/addon-jest wants `options.results` & `options.results.testResults`.

There are two possible solutions:

1. use appropriate version of Jest and storybook/addon-jest
2. apply huck in index.js of storybook-jest library, smth like that

   ```
   if (testFiles && !testFiles.disable) {
     //todo: HERE should be your storybook hack
     options.results = options.tests.testResults;
     options.results.testResults = options.results;
       emitAddTests({
       kind: kind,
       story: story,
       testFiles: testFiles,
       options: options
     });
   }
   ```